# Undefined reference to 'jniRegisterNativeMethods' Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, game-boy-advance

I'm trying to build the .so file from available NDK project. But I encounter the 
`undefined reference to 'jniRegisterNativeMethods'` error when I try to compile the code using cmd with `ndk-build`

Here I'm posting the block of that execution

```
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:gba: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lnativehelper
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : gba <= emulator.cpp
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libgba.so
C:/sdk/android-ndk-r10e-windows-x86_64/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot find -lnativehelper
jni/gbalib/nativehelper/JNIHelp.h:108: error: undefined reference to 'jniRegisterNativeMethods'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgba.so] Error 1

E:\Android-Projects-Archieve\Library-Archives\gameboid>
```

I expect it to build an .so file called `libgba.so` Let me know in the comments if you need more info to look into this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shortly before the error there's a big warning about the way you link one of your libraries. Have you tried doing what the warning suggests?

Comment: No, I didn't do anything for that.

Comment: Even if I remove `-lnativehelper` (in the warning) same error comes. by the way warning disappeared.

Comment: The warning doesn't just say that you should remove `-lnativehelper`. It also says that perhaps you should add the library to your `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` or `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`, depending on what kind of library it is. That's assuming that you actually need that library, which I'm guessing that you do since you're getting undefined references.